# Unnesting and inserting json data in seperate rows and columns in postgresql (10.3)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have the following data set:

```
{"date":{"year":2017,"month":7,"day":2},"data":{"param1":[10,20,30,440],"param2":[55,65,75,85],"param3":[43,55,71,72]}}
```

I retrieve the data from a table called rawData.

Now I want to unnest the values inside the arrays and put them in 4 separate rows and columns inside another table (seperateData), so for this example it would look like:

```
year  | month | day | param1 | param2 | param3

2017      7      2      10       55       43
2017      7      2      20       65       55
2017      7      2      30       75       71
2017      7      2      440      85       72
```

I am guessing I have to use unnest and ordinality to achieve this, but am stuck at how I should proceed. The arrays param1, param2, param3 are always of the same length.

I've already made a fiddle with the data:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jZhYLEvdSERzLCDyoAJz65/0

Comment: What PostgreSQL version do you use?

Comment: @RaymondNijland I am using version 10.3

Answer (score 1):

Properly not the best way to do it mine PostgreSQL experience isn't that great but it works.

**Query**

```
  SELECT   
      ((rawData.values)::json->'date')::json->'year' AS year
    , ((rawData.values)::json->'date')::json->'month' AS month
    , ((rawData.values)::json->'date')::json->'day' AS day  
    , JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(((rawData.values)::json->'data')::json->'param1') AS param1
    , JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(((rawData.values)::json->'data')::json->'param2') AS param2   
    , JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(((rawData.values)::json->'data')::json->'param3') AS param3
  FROM
   rawData
```

demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jZhYLEvdSERzLCDyoAJz65/1

The query also works when the arrays param1, param2, param3 are not equal length.

demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jZhYLEvdSERzLCDyoAJz65/4

> Thanks for your answer, it works so far. Only thing I forgot was, I
>   actually need the index too as a separate column. So the index of the
>   array elements. Any idea

Thats possible with GENERATE_SERIES in combination with JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH

**Query**

```
  SELECT   
      ((rawData.values)::json->'date')::json->'year' AS year
    , ((rawData.values)::json->'date')::json->'month' AS month
    , ((rawData.values)::json->'date')::json->'day' AS day  
    , JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(((rawData.values)::json->'data')::json->'param1') AS param1
    , GENERATE_SERIES(1, JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH(((rawData.values)::json->'data')::json->'param1')) AS param1_array_index
    , JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(((rawData.values)::json->'data')::json->'param2') AS param2   
    , GENERATE_SERIES(1, JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH(((rawData.values)::json->'data')::json->'param2')) AS param2_array_index    
    , JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(((rawData.values)::json->'data')::json->'param3') AS param3
    , GENERATE_SERIES(1, JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH(((rawData.values)::json->'data')::json->'param3')) AS param3_array_index        
  FROM
   rawData
```

see demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jZhYLEvdSERzLCDyoAJz65/6

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works so far. Only thing I forgot was, I actually need the index too as a separate column. So the index of the array elements. Any ideas?

Comment: "Thanks for your answer, it works so far. Only thing I forgot was, I actually need the index too as a separate column. So the index of the array elements. Any ideas?" @web_student i've updated mine answer.. You might want to change `GENERATE_SERIES(1, ...)` to `GENERATE_SERIES(0,..)` because array indexes normally start with 0